# Replacing several elements in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector

```
dat <- c("A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "E", "E", "F", "D", "D", "A", 
         "C", "C", "E", "F", "B", "F", "E", "C", "D", "B", "A")
```

How would I replace as such:

- All "A" values become "D"
- All "B" values become "E"
- All "C" values become "F".

I realize I can accomplish this by using match or which functions in R, but I want to do all this in one line, and also efficiently.

Comment: What have you tried? Why does it have to be one line? Why should we ignore the lack of quotes?

Comment: I didn't feel like writing so many quotes, around each of the vector elements. And it has to be one line, because I gave a very simplified example of the real issue. My real (and more complex) issue involves around 30 replacements. Why should I write 30 which or match statements? Seems silly. And I have tried the replace function, specifically trying to map a vector with elements that must be located (A, B, C) to what it will become (D, E, F)

Comment: So I tried replace(dat, c("A", "B", "C"), c("D", "E", "F)), essentially, and it didn't work correctly.

Comment: Giving a minimal sample is nice; but it should be runnable. This just means the person that answers the question needs to spend the time putting on the quotes to test any possible solution.

Comment: Okay I'll put quotes jeez.

Comment: Although there is nothing to really run here. I feel like my question is quite basic, and me being new to R, I feel like this isn't too complex of a task.

Comment: It's not about complexity. There are often many ways to complete a task depending on intent. It's simply an SO courtesy.

Comment: Could have wrapped as.character(expression)...)) around that comma-separated bunch of tokens. `dat <- as.character(expression(A, B, C, B, A, E, E, F, D, D, A, C, C, E, F, B, F, E, C, D, B, A)` Or `sample(LETTERS, 30, repl=TRUE)`

Comment: Haha that's funny. That's another useful trick I shall be sure to note down. As I admit I am quite lazy when it comes to writing quotes :)

Comment: @BondedDust, `scan` seems nicer...

Comment: Right: `scan(text="A, B, C, B, A, E, E, F, D, D, A, C, C, E, F, B, F, E, C, D, B, A", what="", sep=",")` although you get leading spaces.

Comment: @BondedDust, `strip.white = TRUE` :-)

Comment: Ananda rocks! That's an excellent parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a solution, in one line.

```
chartr(old="ABC", new="DEF", dat)
```

Comment: Thanks, a simple elegant solution with just one line. Just a quick handy function that you learn along the way :)

Comment: @user3562276, another useful function (if you don't like quotes for an example like this) is `scan`. `dat <- scan(what = "", text = "A B C B A")`.

Comment: I actually just noticed this function the other day.  Quite useful.

Comment: Nice. Coming from Java, it is quite nice to see so many inbuilt ways to assist lazy people, whereas the syntax in Java is quite tight, R is much more loose in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

utf8ToInt and intToUtf8 convert characters to and from inters, respectively.  Since A, B, and C to D, E, and F are all three letters away, you can do it by converting to integers, adding three, and converting back, as follows:

```
> vUtf8ToInt <- Vectorize(utf8ToInt)
> vIntToUtf8 <- Vectorize(intToUtf8)
> 
> data <- c("A", "B", "C")
> 
> vIntToUtf8(vUtf8ToInt(data) + 3)
  A   B   C 
"D" "E" "F"
```

Note that these functions don't natively act on vectors, and so must be vectorized first.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- substitute(expression(A, B, C, B, A, E, E, F, D, D, A, C, C, E, F, B, F, E, C, D, B, A), 
                  list(A="D", B="E", C="F") )
dat
# expression("D", "E", "F", "E", "D", E, E, F, D, D, "D", "F", 
#    "F", E, F, "E", F, E, "F", D, "E", "D")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
> library(car)
> recode(dat, "'A'='D'; 'B'='E'; 'C' = 'F'")
[1] "D" "E" "F"
```

Comment: Solid. It works, but I have to install a third-party library. Any other methods? Just for my own knowledge, although this gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're going to use `dat` as a factor. So given the vector

```
dat <- c("A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "E", "E", "F", "D", "D", "A", "C", "C", "E", "F", "B", "F", "E", "C", "D", "B", "A")
```

you can recode certain levels of a factor with

```
datf<-factor(dat)
levels(datf)<-list("D"="A", "E"="B", "F"="C")
```

And then `datf` will contain

```
 [1] D E F E D E E F D D D F F E F E F E F D E D
Levels: D E
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also:

```
ifelse(dat %in% c("A","B","C"), c(A="D", B="E", C="F")[dat], dat)
#[1] "D" "E" "F" "E" "D" "E" "E" "F" "D" "D" "D" "F" "F" "E" "F" "E" "F" "E" "F"
#[20] "D" "E" "D"
```